# SASS - reset style rendered on the end and rewrite styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, sass-loader

I have a React app.

index.tsx is the starting point and I import index.scss there.

```
@import '_variables.scss';
@import 'reset.scss';
...
```

In **reset.scss** I have reseting styles:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    // font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

It works fine till I style any component. Every component has its own SASS file.

```
Components
|_ ComponentName
   |_ ComponentName.tsx
   |_ ComponentName.scss
```

For example, I set in Component.scss `h2 {font-size: 200%;}`.

Problem is, that I build an app, the reset styles are put to the end and `h2 {font-size: 200%;}` is overwritten by reset style `h2 {font-size: 100%;}`

[image: example that reset style is on the top off]

**How can I set sass loader that it has to put reset style in the beginning?**

Comment: Try to import reet before.

Comment: Yes, I would like to, but I don't know how to. SASS loader takes first all component styles and then index.scss with imported reset.scss

Comment: put after the import

Comment: I don't import components style files. Sass loader gather it form src/*